# CSV en formato MS-DOS JAVA

Tags: java, csv

Tengo un problema al momento de generar mi archivo `CSV` desde **JAVA** en el *Sistema Operativo* **SunOS 5.10** (en Windows funciona correctamente) el formato que necesito es `MS-DOS` intente con lo que me dice la siguiente pregunta del *SO Ingles*:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098568/csv-and-ms-dos-csv-formats

Pero no me funciona, ademas lo intente con el siguiente código sacado del foro en ingles:

```
public final static char CR  = (char) 0x0D;
public final static char LF  = (char) 0x0A; 

public final static String CRLF  = "" + CR + LF;     // "" forces conversion to string

String twoLines = "Line1" + CRLF + "Line2";   // 12 characters
```

Fuente:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821578/crlf-into-java-string

Igual intente con:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Pero de ninguna de las maneras me ha salido. Les comparto mi código que genera el `CSV`:

```
archivoCsv = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/../salida/"+campaniasBL.nombreArchivoExtraccion),false), ',');
archivoCsv.write("Folio de Campaña");
archivoCsv.write("Nombre de Campaña");
archivoCsv.write("Inicio");
archivoCsv.write("Fin");
archivoCsv.endRecord();
if (archivoCsv != null) {
    archivoCsv.close();
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4098568/579895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparto la solución a mi problema por si alguien en un futuro se encuentra en la misma situación que yo:

```
public class CsvWriter {

    private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
    private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\r\n";
    private static final String FILE_HEADER = "id,firstName,lastName,gender,age";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        //Nombre y directorio del archivo a crear
        String fileName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/csvMsDosformat.csv";
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
            fileWriter.append(FILE_HEADER.toString());
            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                fileWriter.append("Prueba");
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append("Prueba 1");
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append("Prueba 2");
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append("Prueba 3");
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append("Prueba 4");
                fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
            }
            System.out.println("CSV creado correctamente");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al crear CSV");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error al cerrar el CSV");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fuente:

> https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/writeread-csv-files-in-java-example/